# Webfont using @font-face screwing up div size and spacing on iOS – how do I fix it?

Tags: ios, css, font-face, webfonts

I used custom CSS to install an @font-face webfont from MyFonts on my new Squarespace site. The site is completely responsive by default, and the font adjusts perfectly on everything but some iPhone/iPad browsers (it appears to be an issue with ios 10 and earlier). For some reason when the webfont loads, the div size and default positioning are out of whack. The letters are correct, but in the case of the home index menu, the items overlap:

Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZUU8.png) when they should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCrxj.jpg)

and on other pages the headline just runs straight off the screen:

Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcvn9.jpg) when they should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9K1m.jpg).

Android appears to be loading normally, and it adjusts fine on my Macbook. My iPad (ios 11) also looks good, but my client's (ios 10) has the problem, as does my iPhone (ios 10). How do I make sure it loads consistently?

Here's my CSS. Thanks in advance!

```
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/350e6f.css");

@font-face {
  font-family:'SackersGothicMedium';
  src: url('//static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fbca489140b7d05d1be44c/1509673545091/350E6F_0_0.eot');
  src: url('//static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fbca489140b7d05d1be44c/1509673545091/350E6F_0_0.eot?#iefix') 
    format('embedded-opentype'),url('//static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fbca5e9140b7d05d1be6b9/1509673566929/350E6F_0_0.woff2') 
  format('woff2'),url('//static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fbca57f9619ab843b69aba/1509673560243/350E6F_0_0.woff') 
  format('woff'),url('//static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fbca50e2c483cd2608015b/1509673553520/350E6F_0_0.ttf')
    format('truetype');
}


@font-face {
  font-family: 'SackersGothicMediumAlt';src: url('//static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fbca6471c10bfd21731909/1509673572949/350E6F_1_0.eot');src: url('//static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fbca6471c10bfd21731909/1509673572949/350E6F_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('//static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fbca7ae4966baa783e612d/1509673594306/350E6F_1_0.woff2') format('woff2'),url('//static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fbca75085229ec684a6add/1509673589300/350E6F_1_0.woff') format('woff'),url('//static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fbca6d8165f5e83ce3e406/1509673582003/350E6F_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');}


span.collection-nav-item-span{
  font-family: 'SackersGothicMedium' !important;
}

h2.site-tagline{
  font-family: 'SackersGothicMedium' !important;
}

h2{
  font-family: 'SackersGothicMedium' !important;
   text-transform: lowercase; 
}

h1{
  font-family: 'SackersGothicMedium' !important;
   text-transform: lowercase; 
}

blockquote{
  font-family: 'SackersGothicMedium' !important;
  text-align: center;
}

figcaption{
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 10px !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center !important;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1040px) {
  span.collection-nav-item-span{
      font-size: 3.7vw;
  }
}

 .site-branding h1 {
   background-image:url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fcef98e31d1945635645b1/1509748633336/FIG_17_WEB_Logo_1_dark.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
 }

 .has-index-nav.swap-header-color:not(.view-item) .site-branding h1 {
   background-image:url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54206d9ae4b0423f148f0d6c/t/59fcede408522952619026f3/1509748197382/FIG_17_WEB_Logo_1.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
 }
```

I can't edit HTML because it's a Squarespace site, but in case it helps here are some screenshots of HTML for the problematic areas. [Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAq4i.png) [Page Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz85R.png)

If you want to inspect the site itself, it's figcookingschool.com

Comment: Please add your HTML as well.

Comment: Just added screenshots! (can't edit because it's a Squarespace site)